# Is it possible to swap two styles in Microsoft Word or modify the document map?

Tags: microsoft-word, swap, styles

I've been writing a document in Microsoft Word and have been using the default Title style as my main heading for each section and Heading 1 for my sub-sections. However Word uses Heading 1 as the primary style so the document map and table of contents are not showing correctly.

Can I swap the two styles or modify word to make Title the main style, I think swapping them would be a lot better.

Answer (score 0):

If you've styled the document consistently, you can simply change the configuration of a particular style and it will change the look of each item in your document that contains that style.